# Can we update label of NoteAndAttachment object?

Tags: standard-objects, ant

I tried to update the label using Ant, but getting following error -
"Can't deploy non-customizable CustomObject named: NoteAndAttachment".
So cant we update label at all?

Thank you.

Comment: did you read https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_noteandattachment.htm ?

Comment: I'd be surprised if this can be customized since the underlying Note and Attachment sobjects are not customizable